# How to replace crlf with lf in a single file

Tags: windows, git

How do I convert a single file that has crlf line returns to have lf line returns?

git is already correctly handling crlf to lf conversion automatically for files when I push them to a remote repository, but in this particular case I am not doing a push to a repository. Rather, I am uploading a file, using a file field on an HTML form, to a website that requires that the file have lf line returns. So I need to be able to convert this file individually.

My available potentially useful tools available on this computer would be git and Dreamweaver CC 2014.1.  (I'm guessing Word, Wordpad and Notepad are not viable options but I'm open to being corrected.)

I am on Windows 7 and using git line commands.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

The git installation on windows usually includes the [`dos2unix`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dos2unix.1.html) tool.

```
dos2unix <file>
```

But in your case you should use [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) to prevent the file from being converted on windows.

A [`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file can look like this

```
*.vcproj    eol=crlf
*.sh        eol=lf
```

From the [.gitattributes documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes)

> **Set to string value "lf"**
>
> This setting forces Git to normalize line endings to LF on checkin and prevents conversion to CRLF 
>   when the file is checked out.

Just commit the `.gitattributes` file and your file will be checkout out on every system with `LF` line ending.

Comment: Use `echo "$(perl -pe 's/\r\n?//' filename > filename` if you do not have dos2unix.

Comment: @René Link, thank you, .gitattributes worked as a permanent solution.

Comment: BY FAR the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 32):

In Notepad++ on the bottom panel on to the Right, right click on the area Windows (CR LF) and select UNIX (LF) this should replace all CRLFs with LFs

[image]

Below is the setting in IntelliJ at the bottom right
[image]

Below is setting for VsCode at the bottom right
[image]

Answer (score 5):

To convert from Windows-style text to Unix-style text:

```
perl -pe 's/\r$//g' < windows_file.txt > unix_file.txt
```

To convert from Unix-style text to Windows-style text:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\r)\n/\r\n/g' < unix_file.txt > windows_file.txt
```

This "Unix-to-Windows" command is "safe", by which I mean that it won't add extra Carriage-Returns to a file that is already in Windows format. I hope that someone will get some use out of it.

Answer (score 3):

For a single file you can use Notepad++ replace utility:

- Go to Search -> Replace (or ctrl-h)
- In the dialog box select "Extended" search mode
- Set "Find What" to: `\r\n`
- Set "Replace With" to: `\n`
- Click "Replace All"

Answer (score 2):

Word and wordpad are to avoid! **NEVER** try to modify some code with it, they will add extra code for the file.

To convert the line end, you just use  [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) or [Scite](http://opensource.ebswift.com/SciTEInstaller/), then you choose your end of file: Windows, Mac, Linux.

Here is an example using Scite:

[image: scite]

Answer (score 1):

inside your root folder, create a file '.gitattributes' and add this line :

- eol=lf

save the folder and :

git add .
...
all files of your project will LF

Answer (score 0):

You can use `crlf` tool

```
crlf file.txt --to lf       # change crlf to lf
crlf file.txt --to crlf     # change lf to crlf
crlf -R directory/ --to lf  # recursive
```

GitHub: https://github.com/t-regx/crlf