# error: unexpected end of file (expecting "do") for shell script in Dockerfile

Tags: shell, docker

I don't want to have another .sh file with a script and going to add a shell script code promptly in the Dockerfile. However, I receive an error message during the image build:

/bin/sh: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "do")

Here is the part of the Dockerfile with a script:

```
RUN cat .env | while [ read LINE ] \
do \
    envName=$(echo "$LINE" | grep -o "^[^\=]*") \
    echo "PassEnv $envName" >> httpd.conf \
done
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the square brackets `[]`, and use `;` at the end of lines because docker joins lines when sees your `\`'s, so the commands get melt.

This is working for me:

```
RUN cat .env | while read LINE ;\
    do \
      envName=$(echo "$LINE" | grep -o "^[^\=]*"); \
      echo "PassEnv $envName" >> httpd.conf ;\
    done
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue when I forgot to make sure my files I created on Windows and COPYd to Linux container had `LF` (instead of `CRLF`) line endings.
Converting the file to `LF` line endings worked

Comment: It would've been even more helpful if you included "HOW" you converted!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Most text editors, and many standalone tools, can do this. The instructions will vary based on the tool you use. I happened to use sublime text to do my conversion, but any further detail is best reserved for [separate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810758/how-to-replace-crlf-with-lf-in-a-single-file/27814403) on specifically how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` construct expects `do` to be on a separate line (or, to appear after a semicolon). So you probably want:

```
RUN cat .env | while [ read LINE ]; \
do \
    envName=$(echo "$LINE" | grep -o "^[^\=]*") \
    echo "PassEnv $envName" >> httpd.conf \
done
```

Note the semicolon on the first line.